# Using MPI_Reduce in c

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to write a program in c using the MPI library.
In my program I am solving TSP (but not with any special algorithm...).
My input parameters are `int nCites`, `int xCoord[]` and `int yCoord[]`.
I am bundling them into `Coordinates` and using `MPI_Bcast` to make them available to all the threads.

My problem is this: after I've finished calculating the weight of all the paths in each thread, I want to reduce them into one single result, the best one. I've tried using `MPI_Reduce`, but something, and this is where I get confused, causes a segmentation fault (only in one of the threads, usually `root`).

This is the main code and structs:

```
typedef struct Coordinates_t {
    int* x;
    int* y;
    int n;
} Coordinates;

typedef struct PathAndLength_t {
    int* path;
    int pathSize;
    int length;
} PathAndLength;

void comparePaths(void* a, void* b, int* len, MPI_Datatype* dataType) {
    ...
}

int tsp_main(int nCites, int xCoord[], int yCoord[], int P[]){
    int numOfProcs, rank;
    if (MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numOfProcs))
        throw "Error: MPI_Comm_size failed";
    if (MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank))
        throw "Error: MPI_Comm_rank failed";

    Coordinates crds;
    crds.x = xCoord;
    crds.y = yCoord;
    crds.n = nCites;

    MPI_Datatype data;
    createInDataType(&crds, &data);

    if (MPI_Bcast(&crds, 1, data, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD))
        throw "Error: MPI_Comm_size failed";

        ...

    PathAndLength* pal = (PathAndLength*)malloc(sizeof(PathAndLength));
    pal->path = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*crds.n);

    pal->length = min_length;
    for (int i = 0; i < crds.n; ++i) {
        (pal->path)[i] = min_path[i];
    }
    pal->pathSize = crds.n;
    MPI_Datatype outDatatype;
    MPI_Op op;

    createOutDataType(pal, &outDatatype);

    MPI_Op_create(&comparePaths, 1, &op);

    PathAndLength* result = (PathAndLength*)malloc(sizeof(PathAndLength));
    result->path = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*crds.n);
    MPI_Reduce(pal, result, crds.n, outDatatype, op, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    ...

    return result->length;
}
```

And these are the `createOutDataType` and `createInDataType` I use in my code:

```
void createInDataType(Coordinates* indata, MPI_Datatype* message_type_ptr) {
    // Build a derived datatype
    int block_lengths[3];
    MPI_Aint displacements[3];
    MPI_Aint addresses[4];
    MPI_Datatype typelist[3];

    // First specify the types
    typelist[0] = typelist[1] = typelist[2] = MPI_INT;

    // Specify the number of elements of each type
    block_lengths[0] = block_lengths[1] = indata->n;
    block_lengths[2] = 1;

    // Calculate the displacements of the members relative to indata
    MPI_Address(indata, &addresses[0]);
    MPI_Address(indata->x, &addresses[1]);
    MPI_Address(indata->y, &addresses[2]);
    MPI_Address(&indata->n, &addresses[3]);
    displacements[0] = addresses[1] - addresses[0];
    displacements[1] = addresses[2] - addresses[0];
    displacements[2] = addresses[3] - addresses[0];

    // Create the derived type
    MPI_Type_struct(3, block_lengths, displacements, typelist, message_type_ptr);

    // Commit it so that it can be used
    MPI_Type_commit(message_type_ptr);
}

void createOutDataType(PathAndLength* outdata, MPI_Datatype* message_type_ptr) {
    // Build a derived datatype
    int block_lengths[2];
    MPI_Aint displacements[2];
    MPI_Aint addresses[3];
    MPI_Datatype typelist[2];

    // First specify the types
    typelist[0] = MPI_INT;
    typelist[1] = MPI_INT;

    // Specify the number of elements of each type
    block_lengths[0] = outdata->pathSize;
    block_lengths[1] = 1;

    // Calculate the displacements of the members relative to outdata
    MPI_Address(outdata, &addresses[0]);
    MPI_Address(outdata->path, &addresses[1]);
    MPI_Address(&outdata->length, &addresses[2]);
    displacements[0] = addresses[1] - addresses[0];
    displacements[1] = addresses[2] - addresses[0];

    // Create the derived type
    MPI_Type_struct(2, block_lengths, displacements, typelist, message_type_ptr);

    // Commit it so that it can be used
    MPI_Type_commit(message_type_ptr);
}
```

Sorry for including so much code, but I couldn't decide what, if any, was irrelevant...
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PathAndLength* result = (PathAndLength*)malloc(sizeof(PathAndLength));
result->path = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*crds.n);
MPI_Reduce(pal, result, crds.n, outDatatype, op, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

you are receiving `crds.n*outDatatype`s into result buffer of size `sizeof(PathAndLength)`.  You seem to have design flaw.

Comment: +1, it should be just 1 `outDatatype`: `MPI_Reduce(pal, result, 1, outDatatype, op, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

Comment: So this is what's going on here? I was under the impression that `outDatatype` will be inserted into `result`, and `crds.n` is just a parameter for my convenience which will be sent to my `MPI_Op` function.
Dude, that right there is 12 hours of debugging... RTFM huh?

Comment: @sus most likely, but hard to tell: PathAndLength has pointer members - not mpi friendly

Comment: @aaa: I'd rather say "not developer friendly". There's nothing wrong with pointer members as long as you're entirely clear on what goes where in the memory of each process, and define the datatype accordingly. The solution in the question does look alright to me, though.

Comment: @sus, it did look right to me too, but after I fixed the previous code like you suggested (...result, 1, outDatatype...), I still had some memory access issus. Plus, it flet like I was lying when saying that I only have one datatype. So I changed the design a bit, moved the pointer out of the struct and now everything seems to be working fine.